# Additive Or Multiplicative Time Series Model?

Tags: statistics

So i Just have a question,for the time series graph 
https://gyazo.com/c8246b91ff891fa4177b3d4f22fb4acc (UPDATED)

The time series graph shows the amount of box office sales in $US millions over a 17 year period.

Would a additive or multiplicative model best fit this graph? In my personal opinion I think a multiplicative model would best fit this graph, as it appears that there is alot of seasonal spikes appear to vary in different size and magnitude. However I am not certain.

Comment: I have a feeling that there is not enough information to answer the question. It's because there is no information given about the variables/factors that affect this time series. What is it composed of?

Comment: @MattiP. Added more information